# Global files within MVC-PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Just tinkering around with MVC in PHP for the first time. I'm following a simple tutorial where I've stumbled upon a problem which isn't mentioned in the current tutorial: What is the correct way to include global files (such as header and footer) within the MVC principles if I want to include some special functions for each page (inside the header and/or footer)?

Say I've got a "log page" and a "home page" which both includes the footer.php. However on the "log page" I want some additional text in the footer (to keep it simple). Making separate files is one solution but that feels awkward and also breaks the MVC principle in my mind.

Another solution is perhaps to pass the $_REQUEST from the controller which determines what view should be loaded into the footer - but that again seems to break up the MVC as this, in my mind, is application logic?

The third solution which I'm starting to believe is the best (keep in mind I'm learning!) is to pass data from the model via the controller to the footer and header in the same way I do for page views, thus making header and footer views in their own.

Comment: the model passes data to a view? wont be MVC. the controller has to get the data from the model and tells then the view ...
to break up a header-body-footer template structure has nothing to do with MVC (view is view).

Comment: Yeh, I wasn't clear enough. The data goes from model to controller which then loads and passes data to the correct view.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Z7vXAI0z5I8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is called Layout in MVC and yes, it's a view. Here is a relevant question with an answer: [View in MVC, what is a layout and how to create one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823653/view-in-mvc-what-is-a-layout-and-how-to-create-one)

Answer (score 0):

Since these are global files, the inclusion mechanism has nothing to do with MVC pattern. Although the function inside those header/footer should follow the MVC pattern for their execution.

One solution I can think of is to add this:

```
php_admin_value auto_prepend_file "/Path/to/header.php"
php_admin_value auto_append_file "/Path/to/footer.php"
```

to your VirtualHost Definition.

And add the mechanism to include which view you want to include in these files.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I'll leave the thread unanswered a bit in case someone else wants to append something (I've gotten the impression that there are a lot of interpretations of PHP MVC).